# how to pass textbox values to a method in c#.net for windows forms application

Tags: c#

```
class test
{
    public void read()
    {
       int a=convert.toint32(textbox1.text);
    }
}
```

Error shows that String format is not correct Can any one solve this....

Comment: what is the value of `textbox1.Text`?

Comment: Show your `textbox1.text` value or nobody can help you.

Comment: You can start by writing `Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text)`. C# is case sensitive.

Comment: @MrLister and `textbox1.Text`

Comment: @DGibbs Yeah, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Int32.TryParse` to make sure the value in textbox1 is convertable into `int`

```
class test
{
    public void read()
    {
       int a = 0;
       if(Int32.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out a))
       {
           // a is the integer from the textbox
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("The textbox does not contain a number!");
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that the value of `textbox1.text` is not integer.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably because the text value of `textbox1.Text1` cannot be converted to an `int`.

You might want to consider using [Int32.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx):

```
public void read() 
{ 
    int val = 0;
    if(Int32.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out val))
    {
        //parse was successful
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Input string cannot be parsed to an integer");
    }
}
```

That way, if the parsing fails you can handle it yourself either by displaying an error message as in my example or throwing the exception.